# Windows10のHyper-VでCentOS7使用時マウントが出来ない

Tags: windows

2017年夏くらいからHyper-vをつかってWeb開発用の環境を構築しておりました。
Windows上でファイルを編集、Linux上で実行した結果をWindows上のブラウザで確認、という環境です。

- ゲストOS：CentOS7 (192.168.1.20)
- ホストOS：WIndows10Pro (192.168.1.2)

いつの頃からかゲストOSからホストOSのフォルダをマウント出来なくなっていました。
原因はわかりませんが、調べてみるとWindows10のアップデートが関係しているとの記事がいくつか見つかりました。

対策としては、「Windowsの機能の有効化または無効化」において、「SMB 1.0/CIFS ファイル共有のサポート」内にある以下をチェックするということでした

- SMB 1.0/CIFS Automatic Removal
- SMB 1.0/CIFS クライアント
- SMB 1.0/CIFS サーバ

上記3つともチェックをいれ、Winodwsも再起動してみました。

CentOS7のISOファイルからインストールして作ったゲストOSですが、ログイン後、以下のマウントコマンドを入力しても、エラーが出てしまい、マウントができなくなりました。

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user1,password=passwd1,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=centos7,gid=www //192.168.1.2/www/ /var/www
```

- ホスト側Windowsユーザ：`user1`
- ホスト側Windowsパスワード：`passwd1`
- ホスト側作業フォルダ： `D:\var\www`
- ゲスト側Linuxユーザ：`centos7`
- ゲスト側Linuxグループ：`www`
- ゲスト側作業フォルダ： `/var/www`

mount.cifsコマンドを試してみましたが、同じでした。
以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Vagrantを使って、HyperVをプロバイダ指定可能なboxを落として試してみました。
※box名は`pascalhegy/centos-7.2-64-puppet-hyperv`です。

やはり上記と同じ様に、SMBのマウントでエラーが出てしまいます。

```
==> default: Mounting SMB shared folders...
    default: D:/Vagrant/general => /vagrant
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlmssp,credentials=/etc/smb_creds_vgt-2e7e00e92f59cc95193a0f4a9585a3f6-6ad5fdbcbf2eaa93bd62f92333a2e6e5,uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.1.2/vgt-2e7e00e92f59cc95193a0f4a9585a3f6-6ad5fdbcbf2eaa93bd62f92333a2e6e5 /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

mount error(115)に関して色々調べていたのですが一向に解決に至らず、無駄に時間ばっかりかかってしまいます。ここまで来たらもはやどなたか詳しい方にお願いした方が速いと思い、書き込みました。

知りたいことは以下2つです。

- ホスト側Windowsのフォルダをゲスト側Linuxにマウントしたい
- どうしてこういう事になってしまったのか原因が知りたい

以上、どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "--verbose" オプションを付けると何か原因につながるようなメッセージは出ませんでしょうか？
"-o" に "sec=ntlm" を加えてもメッセージ(mount error(115))は変わりませんでしょうか？

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさま、コメントありがとうございます。
まず--verboseですが、残念ながら1行表示に追加されただけで、内容は-oで指定した内容だけでした。
sec=ntlmも結果は同じでした。両方つけてみましたが、やはり同じ結果になりました。
他の方法もないか調べてみます。